# nginx error "conflicting server name" ignored

Tags: nginx

```
server {
    #listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    #listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    #root /usr/share/nginx/www;

root /home/ubuntu/node-login;
    # Make site accessible from 
    server_name ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com;

location /{
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
    proxy_redirect off;
}
}
```

this results in nignx error [warn] conflicting server name "ec2..." on 0.0.0.0:80 ignored
I dont understand, any explanation appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: There seems to be an implicit default 0.0.0.0:80, adding it explicitly worked for me. listen ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:80; followed by the server_name directive worked.

Comment: Check `/etc/nginx/sites-available/<site-name>` that is linked to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/<site-name>`. Additional files here may contain duplicate or conflicting configuration.

Comment: changing `config.force_ssl = true` to `false` solved my problem, this took me days to figure out

Comment: For me this same error was from a missing semi-colon at the end of one of the `server_name` lines when I had several `server` entries.

Comment: Certbot from LetsEncrypt had added a server block in the default file in my case. It did that cause I tried to get the certificate before I had setup the separate server block.

Comment: In my case I had [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51480365/2195238) `server` block in one file. After I separated them to ist own config files warnings were gone.

Comment: @Kevin THANKS. A nasty semi-colon was missing.

Comment: If you are missing the `listen` directive it can cause the same error to show.

Comment: I dumbly got this error when omitting the semi-colon at the end of the server_name line.

Answer (score 223, accepted):

I assume that you're running a Linux, and you're using gEdit to edit your files. In the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`, it may have left a temp file e.g. `default~` (watch the `~`).

Depending on your editor, the file could be named `.save` or something like it. Just run `$ ls -lah` to see which files are unintended to be there and remove them (Thanks [@Tisch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82028/tisch) for this).

Delete this file, and it will solve your problem.

Comment: fixed the issue for me on Ubuntu 12.04 x86_64 + nginx

Comment: can you clarify? I don't see any "default~" files at all in my

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled 

only the "default"

folder.

Comment: @DavidSaintloth it worked for me and the OP. This is one source of problem, it could be anything else. But to make sure you really don't have the file do: `$ ls -alF /etc/nginx/sites-enabled` normally it's not shown unless you specifically ask for it since it's a hidden/tmp file.

Comment: @DavidSaintloth Check the logs if that don't work, ask a separate question.

Comment: .... where is this `default~` file located?

Comment: @Jakobud in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`. I have edited my answer to mention it.

Comment: In my case nginx.conf had the include for the sites-enabled folder twice. removing one solved the problem

Comment: I had a .save file that was causing the issue.

Comment: n had removed backup files (`default~`) from `sites-available` too

Comment: In my case some configuration of emacs created a file with a leading and trailing `#`, e.g. `#portal#`.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem! I had followed a tutorial and did not realize keeping the "hello world" file in /etc/nginx/sites-available would be an issue. I removed it and default, only keeping the file I wanted to deploy and that fixed my issue.

Comment: Nice you can do `ls -la /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`end then `rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` **be careful dont delete**

Answer (score 45):

You have another `server_name ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com` somewhere in the config.

Comment: I checked for that and didn't find any. it does not give this warning when i remove the "ec2_xxx ...". Is there an implicit default for 0.0.0.0:80 in nginx config ?

Comment: [Official documentation](http://nginx.org/r/listen): `default: listen *:80 | *:8000;`

Comment: This was it for me, however it was `localhost`.

Comment: @VBart your link gave me a hint, actually my browser was prefixing https instead of http in my url, thanks

Comment: I used:
cd /etc/nginx/sites-available;
grep -rnw . -e domain.com

Comment: In my case certbot added duplicate configuration into default configuration file.
just remove the configuration from default config file located at /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:

Answer (score 23):

There should be only one localhost defined, check sites-enabled or nginx.conf.

Comment: I had two identical "server_name" directives in two separate *.conf files. Thanks.

Comment: This solved my issue as well. I had placed 2 same server blocks in different *.conf files. Thanks!

Comment: Also, check all files in this directory: `/etc/nginx/conf.d`.  Each domain can appear only once (as a `servername` value) amongst files in that directory, as well.  That was my issue!