# nginx: [emerg] host not found in "localhost:8004" of the "listen" directive

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I am developing a django powered application using `nginx` and `gunicorn`.
Everything was fine, until today which i tried to restart `nginx` which failed. so I tested it with `sudo nginx -t` command and I got this error.

```
nginx: [emerg] host not found in "localhost:8004" of the "listen" directive in
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/808:2 
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

this is `808` config file contents:

```
server {
    listen localhost:8004;
    error_log /var/www/html/burger808/error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8005;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host     $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR   PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
    }

    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /var/www/html/burger808/burger808/static/;
    }
    location /media/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /var/www/html/burger808/burger808/media/;
    }
}
```

I thought it might be some conflicting over `8004` port. So i checked the other congfig files and there were no conflictings.

I wonder what could've caused this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this [smart answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426087/nginx-error-conflicting-server-name-ignored?answertab=votes#tab-top) was my solution

> I assume that you're running a Linux, and you're using gEdit to edit
>   your files. In the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`, it may have left a temp
>   file e.g. `default~` (watch the `~`). Delete this file, and it will
>   solve your problem.

Answer (score 8):

No need of `localhost:8004`.Only need is

```
listen 8004;
```

Comment: What if I'm trying to do domain:com:8004 and need to specify the domain?

Comment: you can put `server_name` . http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I was trying to add custom host "my-website.test" to the nginx config.
What I had to do first is to modify my `/etc/hosts` and add "my-website.test" there.
After that my nginx ran successfully.