# conflicting server name ignored while deploy nodejs application

Tags: node.js, nginx, pm2

I am working in sample NodeJs application on ubuntu 14.04, now I need to deploy this sample application on to the server. For that I have used Nginx with PM2 for NodeJs. I have followed each and every step in the following URL - [Setup NodeJs with Nginx and PM2 on Ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-14-04) to setup deployment.

Once all the setup completed and when I try to run my application, I am getting error as **`conflicting server name ignored`**

This are the version which I'm using for nodejs application.
NodeJs Version - v8.10.0
NPM Version - 5.6.0
Express Version - 4.16.0

```
/etc/nginx/site-availables/default

server {
     listen 80;
     server_name ip_address;

      location /test-app {
        proxy_pass ip_address;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
     }
  }
```

Note: In location the /test-app is located in /root/test-app. Please let me know if I were wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look here, it might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/14011446/3284355

Comment: @Molda yes I tried too and I didn't find any .save file. When I run the command ls -lah and i'm getting drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Mar 27 01:22 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4.0K Mar 27 01:22 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   34 Mar 26 08:25 default -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/default