# How can I redirect non-www to www in https NGINX

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, jwilder-nginx-proxy, winginx

I have a question related with Nginx redirects
Bellow you can see configurations.
My goal is to redirect from https://example.com to https://www.example.com

I looked through almost all in stackoverflow and I didn't find any help. Please help me with this issue. I will provide all necessary information about my Nginx Web Server.
I hope you will help me, with this difficult question.

My file `nginx.conf` looks like there:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections 768;
}

http {
  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  keepalive_timeout 65;
  types_hash_max_size 2048;

  server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;

  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

  gzip on;
  gzip_static on;
  gzip_disable "msie6";

  gzip_vary on;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_comp_level 9;
  # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
  gzip_http_version 1.1;
  gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xm$

  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

My file `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example:`

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name www.example.com;
  ssl_stapling on;
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

  root /var/www/example/public;
  index ../views/index.html;

  location /img/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3010;
    proxy_cache off;
    proxy_cache_key "$proxy_host$uri$is_args$args";
  }

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3010;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }

  location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|css|js|html)$ {
    root /var/www/example/public;
    expires 1y;
    access_log off;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have registered subdomain www in your DNS config?

Answer (score 13):

Just create a server for non-www requests, for example:

```
# redirect http to https
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
} 

# redirect http://example.com to https://www.example.com
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;

    # ssl ...

    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

# https://www.example.com
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.example.com;

    # ssl ...
}
```

The DNS records for `example.com` and `www.example.com` should be pointing to your Nginx server

Comment: Output logs:
This site can’t be reached
https://example.com/ is unreachable.
ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE

Comment: @MinMIna can you resolve (DNS) the domains within your instance/ server?

Comment: I am sorry but I don't know how it is done.
Can you help me how to resolve DNS?

Comment: Go to the site when your site domain name registered and see instruction how to see and change subdomains yours site

Comment: Why I need to change subdomains of my site?

Comment: @MinMIna just ensure that your domain records `@` and `www` at least are pointing to your Nginx server IP

Comment: Ok, I will try to check it.

Comment: Thank you very much, your advice was correct.
I just added to record A example.com and appropriate IP address and all works.

Comment: If you will see `conflicting server name` warning see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426087/nginx-error-conflicting-server-name-ignored#comment115737927_11426087) note.

Comment: This is the right answer. Works for me!

Comment: did I need to generate the ssl certificate for the non ssl or just use the www's certificate?

Answer (score 2):

Quick instruction for redirect and also for ssl

Don't write all conf all your sites in one file `nginx.conf`. Separate these. You have two folders for it `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` and `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`

Add file for your site for example `/etc/nginx/sites-available/example`
Make link `ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example`

To this conf file paste text below:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com www.cova.company;
  return 301 https://www.example.company$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name www.example.com;
  ssl_stapling on;
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.site.com/fullchain.pem;     
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.site.com/privkey.pem;
  # your location there a
}
```

In you `nginx.conf` ypu already have row `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;` it means automatically take all of their sites configs from folder `sites-enabled`

After it check syntax with command `nginx -t` and reload your nginx with command `systemctl reload nginx`

And after all off this who call your site via http://example.com or https://example.com will be redirected to https://www.example.com

Comment: Unfortunately, I have done as you wrote here and anything happened. I enter command in terminal: curl -I example.com and get logs: curl: (7) Failed to connect to example.com port 443: No route to host
But I used service nginx restart instead of systemctl reload nginx command

Comment: Do you have an ssl certificate?

Comment: Sure, here path: ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot

Comment: Did you called `nginx -t` with no warnings or errors?

Comment: username@name:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled# nginx -t

nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok

nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

Comment: Did you drop everything after **site-enable** in your example?

Comment: Yes, I dropped all.

Comment: Please rewrite your question, how configs looks after changes

Comment: There is no server here to catch https traffic without the www

Comment: Just cut www - it will works